# Is "a ten-minutes of a song" right?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm curious about if "I need a ten-minutes of 'SONG' to do sth." was right in English. Thanks for reading this quesiton

Comment: Hello Tommy. Would you show what research you've done, explain where you think you heard it ...? That will make your question more acceptable here.

Comment: Hmm, just want to figure out if this sentence is right to use. :-)

Comment: No, it sounds like you just want others to figure out if this sentence is right to use. And you're withholding evidence.

Comment: Sorry, it actually means – "a duration of one song", and I want to know how to specific the time "10-minutes" for the duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the "a" and your sentence will make sense:

> I need ten minutes of 'SONG' to do sth.

Or else add in a description of what you need ten minutes of:

> I need a ten-minute **section** of 'SONG' to do sth.

Comment: There shouldn't be a hyphen in *"ten minutes of song"* (although *"ten-minute section"* is fine).

Comment: 'I need ten minutes of complete silence' and 'We need three hours of sustained effort' would be quite acceptable. With some other noun groups, the expression would probably not be considered wrong, but might be considered a rather tongue-in-cheek remark: ?'We need half an hour of sustained knitting' / '?'I need ten minutes of ballet'. 'Song' possibly just falls in this category.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds as if an idiom from another language has been translated word for word into English. It does not make sense in English. There is no expression like that, as far as I know. So, no, it is not correct in English.

You may want to detail what language the expression comes from and what the idiom means.

Comment: Well, it actually means – "a duration of one song", and want to know how to specific the time "10-minutes" for the duration.

Answer (score 0):

With the clarification in the comment ("a duration of one song that lasts for ten minutes"), I now know what you are asking. What you want to say is:

> We need a ten-minute long song.

You can also say:

> We need a song that lasts ten minutes.

if you can't remember the phrase *"ten-minute long"*.